# Velocity vector $= 2î +3j +4k$. How is this vector 1D despite all the three axes being involved?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, linear-algebra

```
    velocity vector = 2î + 3j + 3k
```

How can this vector be 1D despite there being all the three axes involved

Comment: I'd say that calling that one-dimensional is not helpful.  Yes, a vector can represent an oriented line segment.  But it's also a single point in a vector space, and can be thought of as a zero-dimensional object.  And as you point out, that particular vector lives in a 3D space.   If you understand what a vector is, which you seem to, then vocabulary can be understood in context.

Answer (score 1):

Any vector is a line segment. So 2i+3j+3k or 2i+3j+4k or any other vector is one dimensional.